# How to combine two lists in a single list with different elements in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python

I have  `list_a` as `['A','B']` and `list_b` as `['C','D']`

output I have to get is in this format `[['AC','BC'],['AD','BD']]`

When I tried with this below code:

```
output = []

for a in ['A','B']:

    for b in ['C','D']:
        if a !=b:
            output.append([a,b])
print output
```

I Got output as `[['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D']]`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Define lists `a` and `b`:

```
>>> a = ['A','B'];  b = ['C','D']
```

Now, combine them:

```
>>> [ [x + y for x in a] for y in b ]
[['AC', 'BC'], ['AD', 'BD']]
```

#### Explicit Looping

If you really must do explicit loops:

```
outer = []
for y in ['C','D']:
    inner = []
    for x in ['A','B']:
        inner.append(x + y)
    outer.append(inner)
print(outer)
```

This results in:

```
[['AC', 'BC'], ['AD', 'BD']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable explanation John

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you're looping in the wrong order...

```
output = []
for b in list_b:
    output.append([a + b for a in list_a])
```

gives you `[['AC', 'BC'], ['AD', 'BD']]` as desired.

Comment: @Bhanu, great!  So please accept either John's sophisticated answer or my simpler one so the question is seen as resolved.